# Sending commands to mutliple EShells in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I wish to start up a number of processes when I startup emacs,such as a webserver in one eshell, and an instance of weblogic in another shell, but whenever I try to send a command to an eshell then Emacs just hangs. I have tried using the "interactive" command as well, but Emacs still hangs.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? (interactive) is more of a flag than a real command, IIRC.

Comment: I am trying to automate the running of several scripts I have, so that they start automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(require 'cl)

(defun eshell-run (programs)
  (loop for p in programs for i from 1 do
        (with-current-buffer (eshell i)
          (insert p)
          (eshell-send-input))))

(eshell-run '("program1" "program2"))
```

#### Edit:

If you add the above lines to your init file, the programs listed in the last line will be executed automatically when you start Emacs.

Comment: Whenever I enter "eshell-run" I get the response "Symbol's function definition is void: eshell-run"

Comment: That's meant to be added to your init file (~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el) so it's executed autamatically when you start Emacs.